# Regular expression used in nginx server_name directive

Tags: regex, nginx

Can I get some help explaining a regular expression used in nginx `server_name`. The directive is:

```
server_name (?<account>.+)\.mydomain\.com$
```

I don't get the point of the first `?` though. Also, how I can expand this to match `*.mydomain.com` except `web3.mydomain.com`. I.E.

```
this.mydomain.com
```

Should match, but:

```
web3.mydomain.com
```

Should not match.

Thanks.

Comment: I am guessing that it is a named capturing group.

Comment: correct, so `$account` contains the subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

`?<account>` is just a way of [naming the capture group](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Named-backreferences). So, internally ngix will probably reference the `.+` with the name "account" instead of just "capture group #1".

> Also, how I can expand this to match *.mydomain.com except web3.mydomain.com

You can use a [negated lookahead assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind):

```
server_name (?!web3\.)(?<account>.+)\.mydomain\.com$
```

The `(?!web3\.)` part checks if the string starts with `web3.` if so, the whole expression does not match.

But lookaheads are not very efficient. Maybe you just configure ngix to first look for a match to `web3.mydomain.com` and just if this did not match, try the more general expression?

Comment: According to this regular expression checker: http://rubular.com `(?!web3\.)(?<account>.+)\.mydomain\.com$` does not work as suggested. Try `web3.mydomain.com` match group is `eb3`

Comment: @Justin: This depends on the method used for matching. If the string is checked for a full match, the expression works, although the `$` at the end is unnecessary. If, however, the string is *searched* for a match of the expression anywhere, you will need to prepend a ``^`` to the expression: `server_name ^(?!web3\.)(?<account>.+)\.mydomain\.com$`

Comment: Thanks that is a valid regular expression, but for some strange reason nginx is getting upset: `nginx: [emerg] unknown "account" variable`. Going to try posting on the nginx forum.